# Apache vs Terminal - how to reconcile php versions on Mac 10.11.6

Tags: php, macos, apache, osx-elcapitan

I will be grateful for your help on the issue - I am new to cs, hence I beg you for mercy and clear explanations.

My system Mac OS X 10.11.6 (upgraded just yesterday)

My question:

how to set Terminal to use the same version as apache does, or vice versa – how to set Apache to use the same version as Terminal does? Which way is better? I assume that the fist one is better because OS 10.11.6 comes with preinstalled apache that is connected with a certain php version; so any future upgrade of php, if I decided to install one, will automatically overwrite the older version; but if I change apache’s configurations now, i.e. change the version of php it uses, then I will again have to manually change it if I upgrade php. Please, advise me. Please, note: my goal is to have only one workable php version. I understand that it is possible to have two or more, but my goal - one.

`php –v` shows `5.5.37 version`

but `http://localhost/~username/phpinfo.php` shows `5.5.36 version`

Given I have just upgraded my OS, I believe 5.5.36 is not such a bad alternative.

Here is what I have managed to check:
I) `php --ini`

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/php5/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/php5/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/php5/php.d/10-extension_dir.ini
………………
```

But `http://localhost/~username/phpinfo.php` 
a) `Configuration File (php.ini) Path`   `/etc`

I checked `/etc` and found these files there:

```
php-fpm.conf.default
php.ini.default
php.ini.default-5.2-previous
```

No other files containing “php”.

b) `Scan this dir for additional .ini files`  `/Library/Server/Web/Config/php`

I have tried to go to there, but `/Web` directory doesn’t exist within `Server directory`. Therefore I assume no additional `.ini` files are available for apache at these distanations.

II) command `$ php -c /path/to/php.ini -r 'echo get_include_path()."\n";'`

```
.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php
```

and I didn’t find `PHP's include_path` of my server by checking http://localhost/~username/phpinfo.php

Do I understand correctly that due to these circumstance apache uses 5.5.36 php version and not the 5.5.37 one; and Terminal commands reveal the opposite situation? What are correct steps to change this?
Thank you very much for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

The PHP CLI and the PHP Apache Module are different executables, so even if both are compiled to the exact same version number, they're still technically different

Typically, the CLI application is located at `/usr/bin/php`.

I'm not super familiar with Mac setups, but I *think* the Apache modules will be in **/usr/lib/apache2/modules** so `ls -al /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ | grep php` *should* show you all of the PHP modules that have been compiled for Apache.

To determine which one has been loaded, you'll want to look in **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled** directory

HTH, and let me know if you have follow-up questions

Comment: Peter, thank you. None of suggested places exist on my computer; `sudo apachectl -M` showed modes. But I would like to make CLI and Apache use the same php version. I have checked `which php` and it revealed that CLI is not pointing to `/usr/bin/php` as it should. My attempt to create a link by `sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php` and even by `sudo ln -fs /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php`, didn't work out because on El Capitan, as I have learned here, `/usr` is a protected "rootless" directory, even for admins. Therefore I guess I can't change where CLI is pointing to.